# Converting normalized filter to real frequency filter

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

If I have the normalized bandpass filter below, how would I convert it to a filter with a center frequency of 697Hz and a bandwidth of say 50Hz?

```
wHigh = (3*pi)/4;
wLow = pi/4;

M = 30;

N = M + 1;
n = -(N-1)/2 : (N-1)/2;

hn = 1./( (n+eps)*pi ) .* ( sin( (n+eps)*wHigh ) - sin( (n+eps)*wLow ) );
hn = hn(:);

dw = pi/400;
w = 0.0:dw:pi;

ak = hn;
k = 0;

for wc = w
   k = k + 1;

   expveca = exp(j*[M:-1:0]*wc);
   expveca = expveca(:);

   H(k) = sum(ak.*expveca)./exp(j*M*wc);
end

figure()
plot(w, abs(H));
set(gca, 'xlim', [0 pi]);
set(gca, 'xtick', [0:4]*pi/4);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0','\pi/4','\pi/2','3\pi/4','\pi'});
grid on
```

Comment: I semi-understand it, that's why I'm asking for help here mate. Some of this code was provided, some I added myself. I'm not asking you to solve anything, I'm asking for advice.

Comment: Generally, you'll want to do a substitution like `w = 2*pi*f`, but to do this it's much easier to start from the math equations, since this can often require normalization factors in front of the integrals (or sums), etc. Afaik, it can't be done directly from code: eg, if the `w` normalization factor was `1` and the `f` normalization factor was `1/2pi` (as in an Fourier Transform), how would you know this from the code? That is, I don't think this can be done from the info you've posted, and I don't recognize the equation.

Comment: Also, the term `wHigh = (3*pi)/4` doesn't really make sense here, which makes me think something's wrong. `wHigh` should be an angular frequency (ie, have a temporal element) and it's unusual for it to be a perfect angle like this. So with no information, and things wrong in the code, I suspect this problem is not solvable as posted.

Comment: What is your "real frequency filter" sample rate?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to keep this filter, without redesigning a new one, and use it on "real" situations with what you call "real" frequencies, is to keep the proportions between the normalized filter (i.e. designed at 1 Hz sample rate) and the final situation (with the sample rate you want to use).

You have designed a band pass filter with the following characteristics:

```
Center : 0.250 Hz
Bandwidth : 0.250 Hz
Sample rate : 1 Hz
```

Note that `Center = Bandwidth`. Then if you want `Center = 697Hz` and a `Bandwidth = 50Hz` you will need to redesign a new filter because your requirements do not respect proportions.

You can either have:

```
Center : 697 Hz
Bandwidth : 697 Hz
Sample rate : 2788 Hz
```

Or (exclusive):

```
Center : 50 Hz
Bandwidth : 50 Hz
Sample rate : 200 Hz
```

In these two cases, the proportions are respected so I can use your designed filter.

**But a really important thing to decide first, is your Sample Rate you are working with**.